# How to find parallel tangents for a parametric equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, tangent-line

> For the function
> $$ \vec x(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
>     2t + 3 \\
>     2 - t \\
>     t^3 - 2t^2 + t \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
>  t ≥ 0$$
> Are there 2 points $\vec x(t_1)$, $\vec x(t_2)$, such that the function’s tangent vectors
> at these points are parallel to each other? Find such points, or show that none
> exist.

I know that the derivative of the function is

$$ \vec x'(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    -1 \\
    3t^2 - 4t + 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} $$

and that in order for the tangent vectors to be parallel to each other the functions will equal the same value.  However, I am not sure how to go about finding the values.

Comment: How did you get that derivative?

Comment: Using the rules of derivation.  Like deriving a normal polynomial function.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: What is the derivative of $2t+3$?

Comment: The derivative is 2.

Comment: I think you should check each derivative. Look at the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $x'(t)=(2,-1,3t^2-4t+1)$ and $g(t)=3t^2-4t+1$ is not injective for $t\geq0$. In particular the equation $g(t)=0$ has two positive distinct solutions.

Comment: Would those values be the tangents I am looking for to be parallel to on another?

Comment: @nhoroz Yes. At $t=1/3,1$, the tangents are parallel to $(2,-1,0)$. Similarly at $t=0,4/3$ they are parallel to $(2,-1,1)$ etc..

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thank you very much for you response.  If you would not mind clarifying.  In this case would you only need to use the z value of the vector to find the values as it is a quadratic equation and easily solvable and therefore would hold true for the x and y values of the vector?

Comment: @nhoroz The aim is not to make the tangent vectors equal. The aim is to make them parallel. Since the $x,y$ values of the tangent vector are constant, to make them parallel we need to make $z$ values equal at $t_1\ne t_2$. If $x,y$ were also functions of $t$, then we would have to find $t_1,t_2$ such that $(x(t_1),y(t_1),z(t_1))=k(x(t_2),y(t_2),z(t_2))$ which would certainly be a harder problem.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I see.  Thank you very much for your explanation.