# How to find all points for which the tangent line of a parametric equation (x, y, z) passes through a point

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, tangent-line

> For the function
> $$ \vec x(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
>     2t + 3 \\
>     2 - t \\
>     t^3 - 2t^2 + t \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
>  t ≥ 0$$
> Find all points $\vec x(t_0)$ for which the tangent line passes through the
> point (1, 3, 0).

I understand how I would go about solving the problem if I had a normal polynomial function or only *x* and *y* values.  However, with *x*, *y*, and *z* values I am not sure how to approach the question.

I know that the derivative of the function is

$$ \vec x'(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    -1 \\
    3t^2 - 4t + 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} $$

Would I then have to find the equation of the tangent line and use that with the given point to find the other points?

Comment: You have the tangent vector (as a function of time).  To go through your terminal point ${\bf z} =(1,3,0)$, you must have that the vector ${\bf x}(t) + \lambda {\bf x}^\prime (t) = {\bf z}$ for some scalar $\lambda$ and time $t$.

Comment: You could mention your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3892801) asked 3 hours ago about the same **3D parametrized curve** (it's better to use this word in a geometrical context).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you for your reply.  Would I then solve each value of the vector as a polynomial and then solve as a system of simultaneous equations to get the values for  and ?  For example: 2 + 3 + 2 = 1 and then do the same for the other values, etc.

Comment: @JeanMarie I did not realise I could do that.  In future I will.  Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @nhoroz:  Once you have an equation for $t$ and $\lambda$, you solve for possibly multiple values of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Just write the vectors $\vec x(t)-(1,3,0)$ and $\vec x'(t)$ are collinear:
$$\frac{2t+3-1}2=\frac{-t-1}{-1}=\frac{t^3-2t^2+t}{3t^2-4t+1}\iff t+1=\frac{t^3-2t^2+t}{3t^2-4t+1}=\frac{t(t-1)^2}{(3t-1)(t-1)}=\dotsm$$